# How do I install gvfs-info?

Tags: command, gvfs

I need to solve this error

./register_extension.sh: line 28: gvfs-info: command not found

I already tried sudo apt-get install gvfs-info but it doesn't work. I also tried to update but it is still not working.

Comment: Looks like the command is provided by the `gvfs-bin` package. Also looks like the command has been deprecated and replaced by `gio info` (provided by `libglib2.0-bin`). If this doesn't work, please list your operating system.

Comment: Not workin yet. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Comment: Strange. On a fresh Docker instance of Ubuntu 20.04.1 I can run `apt update; apt install gvfs-bin`, which installs the file `/usr/bin/gvfs-info`.

Answer (score 0):

`gvfs-info` [has been deprecated](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gvfs-info.1.html) in 2016 in favor of `gio info` which is the tool you should now use.

However, as it looks like it was deprecated with [this commit](https://github.com/GNOME/gvfs/commit/2f28fa49cfeb1c82927a1c7c0021b15e2742149f) I suppose you theorically could still install `gvfs-info` by manually installing it from an anterior version of the sources. But I'd advice against it and suggest to rather use the new tool.